# cout elements by class and status, jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_1" class="cat" name="cat1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_2" class="cat" name="cat2" value="1" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_3" class="dog" name="dog" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_4" class="cat" name="cat3" value="1" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_5" class="dog" name="cat2" value="1" checked>
```

How count checkbox where class is "cat" and this checkbox is selected (with jQuery)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var count = $('.cat:checked').length;
```

the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=checkbok].cat:checked").count()
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
$('input[type=checkbox].cat:checked').size()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/56Ztn/1/